# Where to initialize Factory object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, singleton, war, factory-pattern

I'm used to creating Singletons to implement a globally shared state, and I'm reading about how Singletons aren't testable and that the Factory pattern should be used instead. The problem I'm having is that I can't see where would be a good place to create the Factory object, in order for it to be accessible everywhere.

Most online examples of the Factory pattern show the object creation in the `Main` method. I'm programming in the context of a Web application which is packaged in a WAR.

For example, let's say I have `ServletA` and `ServletB`. `ServletA` creates an instance of the `FactoryClass` but when `ServletB` is invoked, it won't have access to the `FactoryClass`'s instance.

I'm new to trying to implement the Factory pattern and I want to try do it "the right way", instead of using a Singleton. Also, I want to be able to write more testable code.

Comment: Can your factory have static method/s?

Answer (score 0):

I think you brought up two problems here. First is about to encapsulate object creation responsibility in order to follow DRY principle (instead of repeating instantiation of certain class all over the place) and Factory pattern allows you to accomplish this. Second one applies to populating dependencies in your classes and is more complex concern but allows you to create more separated code.

If your application is simple (and I mean really simple), creating factory instances in each class that need it directly would be satisfying. Second option (if you have many factories and target objects) would be creating some kind of Service Locator, so classes which need some dependency would "ask" for it via dedicated method. Third way (and in my opinion most proper) - you should use Dependency Injection, which provide you a external mechanism for "injecting" instances into your objects. This way, your code is very testable, encapsulated and readable. On other hand it requires you to use some framework that implements DI like Spring or PicoContainer/NanoContainer etc. Much more details about DI and IoC concept you can read in great article [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to only have one factory instance that could be used across the application, otherwise, when I create the factory instance, it would need to set itself up every time.

Comment: So the Factory should be [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instance or a Service provided by Service Locator instance or injected by Dependency Injection mechanism using for example Component and Autowired spring annotations (or in xml config which is a little bit more complex). Anyway it depends on your requirements and scale of your application. Personally I use mainly Spring and DI with annotations.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a Singleton, but it actually looks like the best solution for my application. Thanks